# How to get coordinates from wkt MultiPolygon

Tags: python, wkt

I have a MultiPolygon list in wkt format and I have to get the coordinates from those points.

Could anyone help me please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) Python module to parse WKT geometry and extract the coordinates.

**Try this:**

```python
import shapely.wkt

shapes = [ 'MULTIPOLYGON (((69.0 41.0, 69.0 41.4, 69.4 41.4, 69.4 41.0, 69.0 41.0)), ((59.0 42.0, 59.0 42.4, 59.4 42.4, 59.4 42.0, 59.0 42.0)))' ]

for shape in shapes:
  shapelyObject = shapely.wkt.loads(shape)
  for polygon in shapelyObject:
      coords = list(polygon.exterior.coords)
      print(coords)
```

**Output:**

```
[(69.0, 41.0), (69.0, 41.4), (69.4, 41.4), (69.4, 41.0), (69.0, 41.0)]
[(59.0, 42.0), (59.0, 42.4), (59.4, 42.4), (59.4, 42.0), (59.0, 42.0)]
```